# Перехват onsubmit формы

Tags: javascript, form

Есть форма с обработкой сабмита такого вида:

`<form id="id" name="name" onsubmit="func()">`

Сама форма вызывается на странице ПОСЛЕ загрузки самой страницы и доступа к форме нет (есть доступ только к странице, на которой вызывается эта форма).
Можно ли перехватить функцию сабмита? И выполнять не ту функцию, которая прописана в onsubmit="" формы, а свою?

Comment: сам не пробовал но как насчет document.getElementById("id").onsubmit = "newfunc();";

Comment: или форму завернуть в див - и этому диву так же по id давать innerHTML и код такой же формы но с другой функцией в onsubmit?

Comment: Пробовал, не срабатывает. Срабатывает именно та функция, которая указана в самой форме.
Саму форму в див нельзя завернуть, нет доступа (форма открывается в ajax-окне). Варианты "обхода" я знаю, их не мало, в принципе:) Но мне интересно можно ли 100% перехватит и установить свою функцию. Вот ответ "единичек и ноликов" ниже - уже больше похож на правду:)
Но спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
window.document.body.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  console.log('Отправлено');
},true);
```

Comment: разумеется, не помешает проверка на идентичность формы, если вдруг она на странице не одна

Comment: Сабмит формы отловить удалось.  
Но теперь выполняется две функции. Есть ли шанс отменить выполнение первой, указанной в сабмите самой формы?

Comment: При определении что самбитится именно нужная форма - просто переопределил функцию.  Всё заработало.  
Надеюсь что всё сделал правильно, спасибо:)